# Drawing sin(x) graph in java

Tags: java, graph, trigonometry

I am currently trying to draw the graph of sin(x) in java. I am required by the instructions of my assignment to only use drawLine() as the method of drawing the graph. I can't seem to figure out how to properly set my y value though. Right now what I have is a while loop used in order to draw the line pixel by pixel, but cannot manage to get the y value to be correct. Here is what I have so far.

```
public class GraphJComponent extends JComponent {
public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    Color axis = new Color(128, 128, 128);
    g.setColor(axis);

    int xShift = getWidth() / 50;
    int xShift2 = getWidth() / 100;
    int yShift = getHeight() / 10;
    int yShift2 = getHeight() / 17;

    g.drawLine(xShift,yShift,xShift,getHeight() - yShift);
    g.drawLine(xShift, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() - xShift, getHeight() / 2);

    g.drawString("0", xShift + xShift2, getHeight() / 2 + yShift2);
    g.drawString("1", xShift + xShift2, yShift - (yShift2 / 4));
    g.drawString("-1", xShift + xShift2, getHeight() - yShift + yShift2);
    g.drawString("\u03c0", getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2 + yShift2);
    g.drawString("2" + "\u03c0", getWidth() - (2 * xShift), getHeight() / 2 + yShift2);

    Color line = new Color (255, 0, 0);
    g.setColor(line);






    int x1 = xShift;
    int y1 = getHeight() / 2;
    int x2 = xShift;
    int y2;
    int yScale = getHeight() / 2;
    int sinInput = 0;




    while (sinInput <= 360){
        x2 += (getWidth() / 360);

        y2 = (yScale - ((int)(Math.sin(sinInput) * yScale)));


        sinInput += 1;
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;

    }










}
```

}

Yes I know there are numerous things that I could tidy up or simplify, this is just a rough draft, per-se, that I will clean up once I have everything working. 
I have tried multiple methods of getting the y value to properly be set, the closest I got ended up drawing a straight diagonal lines, it wasn't curved like it was supposed to be. What can I do to properly set the y value so that the sin graph from [0, 2pi] will be properly drawn?

To try to clarify the issue:
The problem lies in changing the y value of my drawLine function. Basically, what I had working wouldn't draw the sin function properly because I only could figure out to lineraly increment it. It looked something like this:

```
 /\
/  \  /
    \/
```

The ultimate question I have is: How can I make it so my y coordinate will scale with the proper y coordinate of the sin(x) graph? In other words, how can I make it "not-straight" and properly curved like the sin(x) graph should.
Thank you for your time I appreciate any help.

The latest thing I've been playing with is something that's sort of like this: The value of the y coordinate is calculated by scaling the value of the sin of the degree and manipulating it with certain factors to get the right pixel coordinate. I think this is the proper way to do it, any thoughts?

At the bottom of this page you can see what the end result should look like:
http://nameless.cis.udel.edu/class_wiki/index.php/CISC181_S2015_Lab3

Comment: `Math.sin` works in radians.

Answer (score 0):

Try y= Math.sin(x)*100;
And take a scale of
1 =100 divisions
That way you can take on the decimals.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. The issue I'm having is properly setting the y coordinates, I am using a 500x250 window and the x axis is on the y = 125 pixel line. Multiplying the sin by 100 wouldn't give me the proper value of y adjusted to my specific window. thank you for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Like immibis pointed out, Math.sin takes an angle in *radians*. Just convert your degrees to radians while passing it to Math.sin, that should solve your problem.

```
Math.sin((sinInput * 2 * Math.PI) / 360)
```